# Number of vertices of 3D Zonotope in general position with all positive generators

Tags: convex-geometry, convex-hulls

Given $d$ generators $G = \{ g_1, g_2, \cdots, g_d \} \subset \mathbb{R}^2_+$. One can obtain the Zonotope via $Z = CH(\{ \sum_{g \in S} g|S \subset G \})$, here $CH$ is convex hull operation.

And the extreme points of $Z$ are also called its vertices. In the 2-dimension, we know the number of vertices of $Z$ is $2d$.

And for some reason, all the 2+ dimensional Zonotope don't have explicit forms for number of vertices.

I've run some simulation for $G' \subset \mathbb{R}^3_+$, and the number of vertices, at least for $d\leq 20$ is $d^2-d+2$. I'm wondering why there is no general form for the number of vertices based on the number of generators.

And I'm wondering does $d^2-d+2$ generalize to $d \ge 20$ cases in $\mathbb{R}^3_+$ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number of vertices of a zonotope is not a function of the number of generators. As a simple example in three dimensions, consider what happens if $G$ consists of three vectors on a plane, and a fourth not on that plane. The generated zonotope will be a hexagonal prism - with 12 vertices.

However, if you chose the generators to be in general position (i.e. no three on a plane), you would get a rhombic dodecahedron with 14 vertices instead. You can imagine that if you took four generators in general position and moved one towards the plane of two others, a part of the dodecahedron would start to flatten - and, eventually, on either side of the polyhedron, three parallelogram faces would merge into a single hexagonal face, eliminating the vertex inside.

In general, the number of vertices in a zonotope generated by $g_1,\ldots,g_d$ is not only a function of the number of generators, but also their incidence structure (i.e. their (oriented) matroid structure - if that's a familiar branch of mathematics). If the generators are in general position, the number of vertices will be

$$2\sum_{k=0}^n{d - 1\choose n}$$

where $n$ is one less than the dimensions of the ambient space and $d$ is the number of generators. This is a polynomial of degree $n$ and agrees with your answer for $n=2$. However, if the generators are not in general position, there will be fewer vertices. Note that incidence structure is the only thing that matters - and it turns out that requiring the vectors to have positive components doesn't affect the possibilities at all.

You can sort of imagine generating vertices of a zonotope as follows: fix some linear function $L:\mathbb R^n\rightarrow \mathbb R$. We want to figure out on what part of the zonotope $L$ is maximized. This is easy: we just add together every generator $g_i$ on which $L(g_i)>0$, leave out those for which $L(g_i)<0$, and can choose what we want to do if $L(g_i)=0$ (in which case, we will get a whole edge or face of the zonotope maximizing $L$). This gives some sense of why we might care if some $g_i$ are coplanar - then we'd find behaviors like a linear function vanishing on three points that we would not otherwise see, and this absolutely affects the resulting zonotope.

If we merely want to *count* the number of vertices, this idea of generating vertices provides a useful perspective: we just need to count how many linear functions $L$ give different vertices. We can do this in a straightforwards way: consider the space $\hat {\mathbb R}^n$ of linear functionals on $\mathbb R^n$ and the planes $\hat g_1,\ldots, \hat g_d$ of linear functionals where $L(g_i)=0$ for the corresponding $g_i$. This is an arrangement of $d$ planes in an $n$ dimensional space. Each time we cross a plane, we change which vertex maximizes the considered linear functional - so the number of vertices is just the number of regions* in $\hat {\mathbb R}^n \setminus (\hat g_1 \cup \ldots \cup \hat g_d)$. One can, from this, derive the above formula for points in general position in a fairly straightforwards inductive argument - though remembering that the incidence structure of the generators can always decrease the count of vertices.

(*In matroid language, that these regions represent maximal covectors of the oriented matroid for the generators - they're the regions we get if we're allowed to specify the sign of each $L(g_i)$. Covectors are the more general concept where we can, for each $g_i$, specify whether we want $L(g_i)$ to be positive, negative, or zero)

Comment: Can you suggest a reference on the formula you wrote?